# How do I make Edits to domain specific sites? eg, es.site.org vs. site.org

Tags: subsites

On site.org I can go to cms-site.org and the edit buttons appear on the page,  which make pages editable. cms-es.site.org doesn't load at all.

Similarly, an administration menu bar appears on cms-site.org, but not on cms-es.site.org (which doesn't load at all).

Is there a way to get these pages to load?

---

I'm using Drupal 7.

When I click on *Configuration* in the menu, I get this. The bottom is cut off but lists my subsite: Site ES.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide more information. What modules do you use? Which Drupal Version? It sounds like that you are using the Internationalization i18n module? You have to create your subdomains and define virtual hosts within your server control panel e.g. cms-es.site.org
cms-en.site.org
... and add them in Drupal /admin/config/regional/language/edit/en